# C# - Getting all of data from device via Serial Port and Detect the Control Character (ACK, SOH, ...)

Tags: c#, serial-port

I can easily receive the data's response from device and show this in Textbox with Serial.ReadExisting(). When showing the data, the problem is some of control character (ACK, SOH, ETX, ...) unprintable.

I try to detect the control character from Serial response with the code below but something wrong in the comparison.

The code is:

```
public bool read_port(ref string rs232data, int timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            int index_read = 0;
            int total_read = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int delay_ms = 1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[serialPort1.ReadBufferSize];
            rs232data = "";
            string buffer_str = "";

            if ((serialPort1.IsOpen == false))
            {
                #if DEBUG
                MessageBox.Show("COM port is not opening");
                #endif
                return false;
            }
            do
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                PauseForMilliSeconds(delay_ms); //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay_ms);
                i++;

                //serial port receive data
                if (serialPort1.BytesToRead <= 0) continue;
                if (i > 1) i--;
                index_read = serialPort1.Read(buffer, total_read, serialPort1.BytesToRead);
                total_read += index_read;
                buffer_str = ToStringLsb(buffer);

                //// Find a Start byte
                int ack_index = buffer_str.LastIndexOf(ToStringLsb(ACK));
                int nak_index = buffer_str.LastIndexOf(ToStringLsb(NAK));

                //Find a Stop byte
                int stop_index_etx = buffer_str.LastIndexOf(ToStringLsb(ETX));
                int stop_index_lf = buffer_str.LastIndexOf(ToStringLsb(LF));

                if ((stop_index_etx < 0) && (stop_index_lf < 0) && (ack_index < 0)) continue; // Can't find a byte Stop


                if (stop_index_etx > 0)
                {
                    if ((stop_index_etx + 1) < total_read)
                    {
                        stop_index_etx++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (buffer[total_read - 2] == ETX)
                        {
                            stop_index_etx--;
                        }
                        else continue;
                    }
                }

                rs232data = buffer_str.Substring(0, total_read);
                return true;
            }
            while (i < timeout);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static string ToStringLsb(byte bytevalue)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytearray = { bytevalue };
            return System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytearray);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static string ToStringLsb(byte[] bytearray)
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytearray);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at a ASCII map and determine which values are the control values you are looking for.

[image: ASCII Map]

So for example I would define the following control characters in my code, then in your `DataReceived` event you can look for those characters.

```
char ACK = (char)6;
char NAK = (char)21;
char SOH = (char)1;
char LF = (char)10;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == LF)
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            CurrentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            //parse CurrentLine here or print it to textbox
        }
        if (c == ACK)
        {
            sb.Append("<ACK>"); //or whatever you want to print
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

edit:
To answer some of your questions in the comments below.  The `DataReceived` event fires when it gets characters in it's buffer, but it could fire while only getting half of your message.  So when using this event, you have to build a string until you know you have the whole message.  In my example above, I'm assuming a LF (Line Feed) indicates I have the whole message.  For you, you would use whatever character you are searching for that marks the end of your message (maybe ACK in your case?). You can choose to append that character to your string or not, it depends on your requirements.  In my example you can see I append the LF but you could easily take that line out.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But when I show it to textbox, it still contains the printable character. Can we delete the printable character after detect with foreach loop?

Comment: It should only print what you put into the `StringBuilder` buffer.  You just need to look for all those characters and if you see one, don't add it to the string.

Comment: If I dont put this character, which is searched, to the StringBuilder via .Append, it will skip for the next one? By the way, if i received the string like "012...789" via Serial Port (.ReadExisting), how can I get the string among them ("3456") ? Many Thanks @Baddack.

Comment: Basically, you're taking the string coming from the serial port's data received event and making your own string (that you will display in a textbox or whereever).  In my example above, instead of putting 0x06 character in my string to be displayed, I'm appending <ACK> to my string, so when you display it in a textbox it's not some garbage character.  However, depending on your requirements you could just do nothing when you see that char and not append anything to your string that you are building.

Comment: I don't know which char you are looking for, but in my example above I know I have the whole string when I see a LF (0x0A).  So I put the whole string into `CurrentLine`, here is where you will want to do your parsing.  I would pass this string to a function where you parse for what you are looking for (ie. "3456").  If ACK is the char you are looking for, use that instead of LF.  You're basically building a string until you have the whole message from the device then you parse it and display what you need.  Hope that helps.  Consider marking my answer the solution if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this term, the device not only sends 1 string, but also the string which sending has some similar characters compare with the old one. So i dont know how to detect them between some responses from the device.